# Docker multiple sites on different ports

Tags: macos, docker

Right now, I have a single static site running in a docker container, being served on port 80. This plays nicely, since 80 is the default for public traffic.

So in my `/etc/hosts` file I can add an entry like like `127.0.0.1 example.dev` and navigating to `example.dev` and it automatically uses port 80.

What if I need to add an additional 2-3 dockerized dev sites to my environment? what would be the best course of action to prevent having to access these sites solely by port, i.e. 81,82,83,etc? Also, it seems under these circumstances, I would be limited to being able to rewrite only the dev site tied to port 80 to a specific hostname? is there a way to overcome this? what is the best way to manage multiple docker sites from different ports?

Note, I was hoping to access the docker container via the container's IP address i.e. `172.21.0.4` and then simply add a hostname entry to my hosts file, but accessing containers by IP address doesn't work on Mac.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    mysql:
      container_name: mysql
      build: ./mysql
      environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=example_dev
        - MYSQL_USER=test
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=0000
      ports:
        - 3307:3306
    phpmyadmin:
      container_name: myadmin
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      ports:
        - 8080:80
      links:
        - "mysql:db"
    apache_site1:
      container_name: apache_site1
      build: ./php-apache
      ports:
              - 80:80
      volumes:
        - ../:/var/www/html
      links:
        - mysql:db
```

./php-apache/Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7-apache
COPY ./config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
EXPOSE 80
```

thanks in advance

Comment: can you add more information about your setup? do you have one container for each website? are your websites composed only by static files and so you don't need custom specific process to serve them (e.g. node, python...)? what is the file structure of your project/s? are you constrained to a specific web server?

Comment: @lifeisfoo, please see my edited response. I added my `docker-compose.yml`, currently I only have one static site. In the future I may have 5-10 sites, some of which are node sites. And, while I am currently using apache (b/c it is what I am most familiar with), I am open to suggestions, if theres a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: can you post your apache configuration?

Comment: @lifeisfoo, please see edited. The apache configuration is all standard/default configuration included with the php:7-apache docker image - no settings added / altered.

Comment: I've update the answer, take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is best handled using a reverse proxy such as [nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/). You can run the reverse proxy on port 80 and then configure it to route requests to the specific site. For example,

```
http://example.dev/site1     route to site1 at http://example.dev:8080
http://example.dev/site2     route to site2 at http://example.dev:8081
```

And thus you run your sites on ports 8080, 8081...

Answer (score 1):

### Specific solution

Based on the docker-compose file in the question. Edit the `docker-compose.yml` file, adding this service:

```
nginx-proxy:
  image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
```

Then, change the `apache_site1` service in this way:

```
apache_site1:
  container_name: apache_site1
  build: ./php-apache
  volumes:
    - ../:/var/www/html
  links:
    - mysql:db
  environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=apache-1.dev
```

Run the docker-compose file and check that your apache-1 website is reachable:

```
curl -H 'Host: apache-1.dev' localhost
```

Or use the Chrome extension as described below.

#### More websites

When you need to add more websites, just add an `apache_site2` entry like you want and be sure to set a `VIRTUAL_HOST` environment variable in its definition.

## Generic solution

### Use a single nginx with multiple server entries

If you don't want to use a reverse proxy with a subpath for each website, 
you can setup a nginx reverse proxy listening on you host `80` port, with one `server` entry for each site/container you have.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example-1.dev;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://website-1-container:port;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example-2.dev;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://website-2-container:port;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
... and so on
```

Then, you can use the `Host` header to request different domains to your `localhost` without changing your `/etc/hosts`:

```
curl -H 'Host: example-2.dev' localhost
```

If you're doing web development, and so you need to see web pages, you can use [a browser extension to customize the Host header](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj) at each page request.

#### Already made solution with nginx and docker services

Use a [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) file with all your and use the [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) image that will auto configure a nginx proxy for you using environment variables. This is an example `docker-compose.yml`file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  website-1:
    image: website-1:latest
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=example-1.dev
  website-2:
    image: website-2:latest
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=example-2.dev
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
```

### Apache solution

Use [apache virtual hosts](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension) to setup multiple websites in the same way described for nginx. Be sure to enable [the Apache ProxyPreserveHost Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost) to forward the `Host` header to the proxied server.

Comment: i'm using apache - not nginx, does the same solution apply?

Comment: yes, you only need to configure apache virtual hosts in the same way

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried this with no luck. Can you elaborate on how to accomplish this with apache? Also, what is the image `website-1:latest`? I typically  copy the website files over using volumes..

Comment: basically looking for a simple docker compose solution where example.dev outputs 'hello world' via a simple index.php file or similar and example2.dev outputs 'foobar'